# select statement inside a insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I tried the below sql query

```
INSERT INTO test.ACT_QUERY values(2139,2,'SELECT ''D'',ORDER_ID from dual');
```

When a java program run this select statement  from test.ACT_QUERY table and spools to a output file it gives a "D", 123.  I just want D,123. Not sure why the quotes are coming up. What i need to replace in the select statement to get the output as D,123

Comment: What is the insert statement that should be executed in the end? INSERT INTO test.ACT_QUERY values(2139,2,'D', 123); ??

Comment: I'm presuming the select statement gets executed and the ouput is written to the output file, in which case the problem lies with whatever is writing the result set to the file not the select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to visualize your problem.  Certainly there is nothing wrong in principle with what you're doing, and it works in PL/SQL.

Here is your test data, slightly tweaked to run in my DB:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO ACT_QUERY values(2139,2,'SELECT ''D'', DUMMY from dual');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from act_query
  2  /

        ID       BLAH
---------- ----------
QRY_TXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      2139          2
SELECT 'D', DUMMY from dual


SQL>
```

Let's roll!

```
SQL> begin
  2      for r in (select * from
  3
  4  .
SQL> declare
  2      v1 char(1);
  3      v2 char(1);
  4  begin
  5      for r in (select * from act_query)
  6      loop
  7          execute immediate r.qry_txt into v1, v2;
  8          dbms_output.put_line(r.qry_txt);
  9          dbms_output.put_line('v1='||v1||'::v2='||v2);
 10      end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /
SELECT 'D'as D, DUMMY from dual
v1=D::v2=X

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, you need to explain your situation in a bit more detail, with cut'n'paste of actual output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Apologies for the late response

Comment: Your correct. Problem is with the java program that is retreiving had issues.  Thanks a lot for your time